# Several 'display' methods not working (LWJGL 2.9.3)

Tags: lwjgl

I'm aware there are newer versions of LWJGL out - but the code I am looking at utilizes the .util class - which is absent from newer versions...

That said - I have imported org.lwjgl.util.Display and org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode, and these methods still don't appear to be recognized:

```
Display.setTitle(WINDOW_TITLE);
Display.setFullscreen(fullscreen);
Display.create();
Display.update();
Display.destroy();
Display.sync(60);
Display.isCloseRequested()
```

Comment: what IDE are you using?How have you imported those jar files into your IDE?

Comment: AndroidStudio. Imported via the 'dependencies' tool in 'Project Structure'.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...
I had imported:

```
import org.lwjgl.util.Display;
```

instead of

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
```

Very frustrating to find same named classes in multiple .jar's  =/